# Django. How to show some content on only single page without duplicating?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

For starters, i'm new in Django.

I have a searchbar and i want to show it on only single page. I use `{%block searchbar %} {%endblock%}` on all pages where I don't want to see the search bar. But suddenly I thought: I'm duplicating the code, and this violates the principle of "DRY". So, how can I display some content on a single page without duplicating this `{%block searchbar %} {%endblock%}` stuff?

In advance, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `include` tag to include the search bar on the pages that you want. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) for more from the docs.

Place the code for the search bar in an HTML file called `"searchbar.html`
and then include it in any pages that you want.

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block bar %}
   {% include "searchbar.html" %} <!-- Simply include this on pages that you want -->
{% endblock %}
```

this way you will not violate the `DRY` principle.